# How to get the line number of the cursor in paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="content" contenteditable="true">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
```

javascript code of this is

```
var divheight = $(".content").height(); 
var lineheight = $(".content").css('line-height').replace("px","");
alert(Math.round(divheight/parseInt(lineheight)));
```

css is

```
.content {
    line-height:20px;
}
```

for example if the click inside `.content` the `<span class="cursor"></span>`

```
.cursor {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: -1px;
    color: #2E3D48;
}
```

how to find the `.cursor` is inthe line number of `.content`

just tried mockup fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/1ok3dah9/

Comment: If it's wrapping, there isn't technically a line number. So I assume you're looking for a pseudo-line number?

Comment: Not clear what your goal is really.

Answer (score 1):

**VERY PRIMITIVE** example (given that `.cursor` is the target and we can deduce its line height to find offset):

```js
;(function($){
  // $(...).lineNumber( [cursorClassName = 'cursor'] );
  // Locates the pseudo-line number of the .cursor within the target element.
  // This is based on two thigns:
  //  1. The target element has a line-height, and
  //  2. The target element has a .cursor element we can position
  // Basic math is performed based on line-height and the .cursor's current
  // vertical offset.
  $.fn.lineNumber = function(cursorClassName) {
    // in case we wanted to target a new class name
    cursorClassName = 'cursor';
    
    // locate the cursor within the current element
   var $cursor = this.find('.'+cursorClassName);
    if ($cursor.length) { // check for .cursor
      var lineHeight = parseInt($cursor.css('line-height').match(/\d+/)[0]),
          topPosition = $cursor.position().top;
      // divide top offset by line height. Apply integer division and return
      // the approx. line number. In this case, lines are zero-based, so offset
      // by 1.
      return ~~(topPosition / lineHeight) + 1;
    }
    return -1; // no match
  };
})(jQuery);

$('.lineNumber').text($('.content').lineNumber());
// Go full-screen to see it work based on window size (e.g. word-wrapping)
$(window).on('resize', function(){
  $('.lineNumber').text($('.content').lineNumber());
});
```

```css
.content {
    line-height:20px;
}
.cursor {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: -1px;
    color: #2E3D48;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content" contenteditable="true">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived<span class="cursor"></span> not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularized in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>

<pre>Line #: <span class="lineNumber" style="color:#f00;"></span></pre>
```

Here's a fiddle if you wanted to play around: https://jsfiddle.net/np8owsbv/2/

I bound the fiddle to window resizing as well and appears to adjust correctly. Could also play with `.cursor` position and see how it fairs.

Comment: super @ Brad Christie, from the cursor row if i press home key the cursor goes to the starting of the paragraph any way to change this as starting of the line